# SQLAlchemy mapping for postgres table seems incorrect

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, sqlalchemy

How to create SQLAlchemy mapping for a table created using Hibernate DDL generation

```
\d watermarks;
                           Table "public.watermarks"
       Column        |              Type              | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id                  | bigint                         |           | not null | 
 created_date        | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null | 
 modified_date       | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null | 
 end_date            | timestamp(6) without time zone |           |          | 
 last_processed_date | timestamp(6) without time zone |           |          | 
 start_date          | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null | 
 status              | integer                        |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "watermarks_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

I am using the following SQLAlchemy mapping, but it doesn't work as expected on insertion, am I missing anything compared to the above table definition which was done using Hibernate

```
class Watermark(Base):
    __tablename__ = "watermarks_test"
    id: Mapped[BigInteger] = Column(BigInteger, Sequence("some_id_seq", start=1), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    status: Mapped[Integer] = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    last_processed_date: Mapped[DateTime] = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    start_date: Mapped[DateTime] = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=DateTime.now)
    created_date: Mapped[DateTime] = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=DateTime.now)
    end_date: Mapped[DateTime] = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
```

Comment: " but it doesn't work as expected on insertion" - how so? PLease be precise.

Comment: So **exactly** what is it doing and what did you expect it to do? Post sample data, expected results and actual results. Include the Postgres table definition (ddl).  All as text **no images** even create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).  Your saying *it doesn't work as expected* is useless, it tells the community nothing that we don't already know - if it worked you would not be posting a question.